# Changing the JSESSIONID cookie name to something else with Spring Boot Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to change the name of the JSESSIONID cookie to something else to make it more difficult for potential attackers to guess what technology my application is using.

Is this possible in Spring Boot with Spring Security? I've been able to find solutions for Spring Boot with Spring Session but none that would work without the Session extension (which I'm not using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change cookie name in your `application.yml`

Like this :

```
server:
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        name: TEST_JSESSIONID
```

or

```
@Bean
public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
    DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    serializer.setCookieName("TEST_JSESSIONID"); 
    serializer.setCookiePath("/"); 
    serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$"); 
    return serializer;
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-custom-cookie.html

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it in your `web.xml` like so:

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <name>cookie name</name>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Comment: I would like to avoid using XML configuration. Is there any way to achieve this without ```web.xml```?

Comment: @JakeS. Not that I know of.